# Is it possible to restrict the bandwidth used by a network client?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to control or restrict the amount of data used by each person or station connected to a WIFI or hard wired Router?

I'd like to bandwidth-limit connections to stop or restrict downloading video streams, as this slows network activity.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible, but it all depends on the equipment you are using. I know for a fact though that this is possible with Pfsense (router/firewall OS), DD-WRT (Custom Router Firmware), and TomoatoUSB (Custom Router Firmware). You could also think about setting up QOS to prioritize traffic over the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free versions of programs like Netlimiter. Non-free versions come with more features, such as more specific control, remote management, etc.